# What's the precision of built-in functions in shading language?

Tags: hlsl, glsles

Precision conversion on mobile devices may cause performance drop. I want to minimize conversion in our shaders(glsles, hlsl and spir-v). I'm confused by the built-in function precision.

Consider the following code:

```
mediump float a, b;
mediump float c = max(a, b);
```

```
mediump float a, b;
float c = max(a, b);
```

```
mediump float a, b;
mediump float c = sin(max(a, b));
```

```
mediump float2 uv;
uniform mediump sampler2D tex;
mediump float c = texture2D(tex, uv);
```

What conversions would happen? If built-in function return type depends on parameters, code #1, #3, #4 should have no conversion. Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can always predict conversions, because shader compilers will optimise to use the lowest precision and fewest conversions where possible. But I suspect you have the wrong mindset and are micro-optimising for something that doesn't matter much. With typical implementations, precision conversions should be very cheap. **What you should be concerned about is unnecessarily using high precision** for your inputs, outputs and other variables, which should have more impact.

The simplest and most optimal approach is to put `precision mediump float;` at the top of your shader, so precision defaults to `mediump`, then test on devices which support reduced precision (i.e. mobile GPUs) and see if anything breaks. You can then **selectively add `highp` where necessary**.